# signalR: On user signout(after the connection stopped), disconnect event is not firing

Tags: signalr

On signout, disconnect event not fired immediately but at the interval of 30 secs defined connection timeout interval in signalR-2.4.0.js.
What are the possible reasons?

In connection stop function of signalR-2.4.0.js, if you use try...finally block and put below code in finally block then it works for 2 users, not for multiple users.

```
// Trigger the disconnect event
changeState(connection, connection.state, 
signalR.connectionState.disconnected);
$(connection).triggerHandler(events.onDisconnect);
```